# Live form validation - How do I check if all the fields are valid?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom

I've just recently started learning Javascript and as one of my first projects I'm creating a form that is validated live as the user types. For each text field, there is a function like "userError()" which checks for the errors. This function is run every time the text field is changed.

It works fine, except for one problem. I have two div's that contain a button. One is the disabled submit button (for when there are still errors in the form) and the other is the real submit button (for when all fields are valid). The function "disableSubmit()" is ran onload so the real submit button is hidden until the form is completed. The function switchButton() is ran every time one field is validated successfully. switchButton checkes to see if all the functions (userError, passError, etc) return true. If they do, the real submit button is revealed and the disabled one is hidden. I figured this would work but for some reason it doesn't. It just shows the disabled button the whole time, even if the form has no errors.

The Javascript:

```
<script>
button=document.getElementById('submit')
password=document.getElementById('password')
function switchButton() {
    if (userError() && passError() && confirmError() && emailError()) {
        document.getElementById('submitbutton').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('disabled').style.display = 'none'; 
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('submitbutton').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('disabled').style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
function disableSubmit() {
    document.getElementById('submitbutton').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('disabled').style.display = 'inline';   
}
function userError() {

    username=document.getElementById('username')
    usererror=document.getElementById('usererror')


    if (username.value.length < 4) {
        usererror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="red"><img src="cross.png" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Username too short.</font>';
        return false;
    } else if (username.value.length > 12) {
        usererror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="red"><img src="cross.png" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Username too long.</font>';
        return false;
    } else {
        usererror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="darkgreen"><img src="check.jpg" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Username looks great!</font>';
        return true;
        switchButton();
    }
}

function passError() {

    password=document.getElementById('password')
    passerror=document.getElementById('passerror')


    if (password.value.length < 7) {
        passerror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="red"><img src="cross.png" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Password too short.</font>';
        return false;
    } else if (password.value.length > 32) {
        passerror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="red"><img src="cross.png" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Password too long.</font>';
        return false;
    } else if (password.value.length = 0) {
        passerror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="red"><img src="cross.png" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Password not entered.</font>';
        return false;
    } else {
        passerror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="darkgreen"><img src="check.jpg" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Password looks great!</font>';
        return true;
        switchButton();
    }
}


function confirmError() {

    confirm=document.getElementById('confirm')
    confirmerror=document.getElementById('confirmerror')


    if (confirm.value != password.value) {
        confirmerror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="red"><img src="cross.png" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Passwords do not match.</font>';
        return false;
    } else {
        confirmerror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="darkgreen"><img src="check.jpg" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;The passwords match!</font>';
        return true;
        switchButton();
    }
}


function emailError() {

    email=document.getElementById('email')
    emailerror=document.getElementById('emailerror')
    var atpos=email.value.indexOf("@");
    var dotpos=email.value.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (email.value.length > 40) {
        emailerror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="red"><img src="cross.png" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Email too long.</font>';
        return false;
   } else if (atpos<1 || dotpos<atpos+2 || dotpos+2>=email.value.length) {
        emailerror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="red"><img src="cross.png" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Email not valid.</font>';
        return false;
   } else if (email.value.length < 1) {
        emailerror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="red"><img src="cross.png" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Email not entered.</font>';
        return false;
   } else {
        emailerror.innerHTML='<font size="2" color="darkgreen"><img src="check.jpg" style="max-width: 10px"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Email looks great!</font>';
        return true;
        switchButton();
    }
    }

    </script>
```

The HTML Form:

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">


                <input type="text" maxlength="12" id="username" onkeyup="userError()" onchange="userError()" class="loginfield" name="registerusername" placeholder="Username" style="height: 20px;" size="50" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="font-weight: normal;" id="usererror"></a><br><br>

                <input type="password" id="password" class="loginfield" name="registerpass" onkeyup="passError()" onchange="passError()" placeholder="Password" style="height: 20px;" size="50" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="font-weight: normal;" id="passerror"></a><br><br>

                <input id="confirm" type="password" class="loginfield" name="registerconfirm" onkeyup="confirmError()" onchange="confirmError()" placeholder="Confirm Password" style="height: 20px;" size="50" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="font-weight: normal;" id="confirmerror"></a><br><br>

                <input id="email" type="text" class="loginfield" name="registeremail" onkeyup="emailError()" onchange="emailError()" placeholder="E-mail Address" style="height: 20px;" size="50" />
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="font-weight: normal;" id="emailerror"></a><br>

                <div id="disabled">
                <p><input id="disabled" type="button" name="registersubmit" value="Sign up for CP Cheats"/ DISABLED> &nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="font-weight: normal;" id="buttonerror"><font size="2" color="grey">Complete the form first!</font></a>
                </div>

            <div id="submitbutton">
                <p><input id="submit" type="submit" class="loginbutton" name="registersubmit" value="Sign Up for CP Cheats"/> 
                </div>

            </form></p>
```

Comment: In general, it's helpful if you tell us what you see.  Describe how it fails, which can help anyone reviewing your code to know what areas might be worth focusing on.

Comment: You have your `return true;` before the `switchButton()`, so that function will never get called . . .

Comment: Oops, can't believe I forgot that! Sorry. (ernie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have your `return true;` before the `switchButton()`, so that function will never get called . . . but if it did, I think you'd be in major trouble, likely causing the browser to become unresponsive.  You're switchButton function reads:

```
function switchButton() {
    if (userError() && passError() && confirmError() && emailError()) {
        document.getElementById('submitbutton').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('disabled').style.display = 'none'; 
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('submitbutton').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('disabled').style.display = 'inline';
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, call that function from within each of the four functions you have to check each field, but then in the if, you're going to call the same check function, resulting in an endless loop of calling `switchButton()`.

You need to remove the `switchButton()` calls from each of the `fieldError()` functions.

If it still doesn't work at that point, make sure your id's are correct.

Comment: Thanks! Instead of putting switchButton() in the fieldError() functions i replaced fieldError() in the form onkeyup event with switchButton. Works perfectly!